# How can I reorganize a directory structure in Perl?

Tags: perl, file

I am writing a script for renaming/copying the content of a file.

I have `temp` & `temp1` folders. Inside `temp1` I have 1,000 `.txt` files with names `1.txt`, `2.txt`, `3.txt` ... & in `temp` folder I have sub directories named `1`, `2`, `3`.

In the folders `1`, `2`, `3` ...,  I have one file with extension `java` or `xml`.

My need is to automate the copy of the contents of the `.txt` file, and paste into the respective file in the temp sub directory. Is it possible to do this using Perl?

Comment: What have you done so far? What do you have difficulty with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [perldoc -f rename](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions.rename.html). You can rename files in a loop.